# Javascript extract value inside parentheses between commas (Increase element's transform function arguments)

Tags: javascript, regex

The context here is simple, I want to capture the `transform` css value from a graphic element and increase it by 10.

In my case the only transform I have is translate, but ideally it would work if there are other ones as well as I only want to change the translate value.

I tagged it as regex but not sure if it's needed.

```js
const myElement = document.getElementById('myElement');
const translateString = myElement.getAttribute('transform');
const newTranslateString = increaseArgumentsBy10(translateString);
myElement.setAttribute('transform', newTranslateString);


function increaseArgumentsBy10(translateString) {
  console.log('To be implemented');
  return translateString;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <text id="myElement" transform="translate(50,50)">My Element
  </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a function `translate` and use `eval`

```js
const myElement = document.getElementById('myElement');
const translateString = myElement.getAttribute('transform');
const newTranslateString = increaseArgumentsBy10(translateString);
myElement.setAttribute('transform', newTranslateString);


function increaseArgumentsBy10(translateString) {
  function translate(x, y) {
    return('translate(' + (x + 10) + ', ' + (y + 10) + ')'); 
  }
  return eval(translateString);
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <text id="myElement" transform="translate(50,50)">My Element
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: That's very, very clever but seems illegal

Comment: @Mojimi you have to use `try {} cacth(e) {}` and it would be totaly legal ;-)